# Sourcemaps not working for React Native Android app in production

Tags: react-native, sentry

I using Sentry to log crashes in my app in production. The sourcemaps are working as expected for iOS app but for Android, I don't the actual file and line number at which the crash happened. The stack trace contains references to index.android.bundle. I use the following command to create the bundle and the map file

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output index.android.bundle --sourcemap-output index.android.map
```

I upload the bundle and map files to sentry using command

```
sentry-cli releases files 1.0.10 upload-sourcemaps --rewrite --url-prefix / ./
```

I wanted to ask whether anyone has been able to get the sourcemaps to work for Android using Sentry. Are there any other instructions that I need to follow to get the sourcemaps to work for Android app?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you just call `./gradlew assembleRelease` if you are running the latest version of `react-native-sentry`.

As described here:
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/#android-specifics

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently, I have been using raven-js to push the errors to sentry. I will move to `react-native-sentry` soon.